# Navbar menu button animation not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I am trying to add animation when navbar-button is toggled on small screen sizes. That's why I have tried to make the same as for .navbar-toggle.larr  [in this template](https://codepen.io/jorenerene/pen/vxKbJb?editors=1100).

```
/* ANIMATED LEFT ARROW */
.navbar-toggle.larr.collapsed .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0deg);
    width: 22px;
}

.navbar-toggle.larr.collapsed .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0deg);
}

.navbar-toggle.larr.collapsed .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0deg);
    width: 22px;
}

.navbar-toggle.larr .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: translate3d(0px,6px,0) rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 11px;
}

.navbar-toggle.larr .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translate3d(0px,-6px,0) rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    width: 11px;
}
/* END ANIMATED LEFT ARROW */
```

This css block will change the menu button from 3 lines to a left arrow when menu is opened and vice versa. I have my own design concerning main menu and side-containers, I don't want to use the one implemented in the example. But unfortunately when I run my project nothing happened. So how can I make it work [with my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kgzf3hex/1/)?

**Update:**

If I remove the collapsed class from button in my demo, the menu button will take the design of left arrow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your Jquery and add just one line to it as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]');
            var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');
            var sel2 = sideslider.attr('data-target-2');
            sideslider.click(function (event) {
                $(sel).toggleClass('in');
                $( ".navbar-toggle" ).toggleClass( "collapsed" );
                $(sel2).toggleClass('out');
            });
        });
```

find the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgzf3hex/3/)